# How to jump right to a specific hour if the hour is less than a given number in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, timer

I have a code that calculates a delivery date by using a "delivery time calculated with minutes" and converting those minutes into an exact delivery date&time.

`$minutes` is the delivery time in minutes.

What I want to achieve is something like:

*"If the hour field(H) is less than 09:00 as a result (or simply between 00:01-08:59) than display it as 09:00 without changing anything else"*

```
function format_delivery_date($minutes, $date_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $now_date = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    date_add($now_date, date_interval_create_from_date_string($minutes.' minutes'));
    return date_format($now_date, $date_format);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you want to set the time to 09:00 on the date after you've added the delivery minutes? That's not clear from your question. It would be a bit easier if you did it before the addition. Simply manipulate the `$now_date`. Something like: `if time < 09:00 then now = 09:00 else now = time` (last bit is pseudo code).

Comment: I think the answer here will be to use date http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to get the hour and then do a if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know if the time is before 9AM. Easy enough:

```
if( intval(date_format($now_date, 'G')) < 9) {
```

`'G'` is 24-hour with no leading zero.

Then just set the time:

```
    date_time_set($now_date, 9, 0, 0);
```

Done.